# How to create grid with fixed box height in CSS?

Tags: css, grid

I am creating a calendar layout in Ruby on Rails and each day box should have equal height regardless of how many events there are per day. This is the CSS I currently have. How can I fix the height of each box to a certain size?

```
.calendar-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 200px);
}

.day-calendar-item {
    background-color: #f4fcff;
    border-width: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need the `grid-template-rows` property. Try to add `grid-template-rows: repeat(x, 200px)` to the `.calendar-container` class where `x` is the number of rows you want and `200px` is the size of each row (although you can change this to your preference).